# Smallest Common Multiple Divisible by

Tags: javascript, algorithm, lcm

I'm working in JavaScript and I am solving for smallest common multiple, for two numbers, and the smallest common multiple has to be divisible by all numbers between the two numbers.

Right now, my code is not working at all and nothing is being returned. I had one function to calculate the smallest common multiple and a second function to determine if that multiple was divisible by the numbers between the smallest and largest number.

```
function smallestCommons(arr) {

    var max = 0;
    var min = 0;
    var lcm = 0;
    var max2 = 0;
       if(arr[0]> arr[1]) {
         max = arr[0];
         min = arr[1];
       } else {
         max = arr[1];
         min = arr[0];
       }

       function range(item){
         for(var j = min+1; j < max; j++){
           if(item % j !== 0){
             return 0;
           } else {
             return item;
           }
         }
       }   
       function lcmFind(min1, max1){
         for(var i =1; i < min1; i++){
             max1 = max1 * i;

             if(range(max1) === 0){
               continue;
             } else {
               return range(max1);
             }       
           }  
         }         
       return lcmFind(min,max);    
     }
     smallestCommons([1,5]);
```

Comment: You could have easily found this if you have done a small research

Comment: There is lots of code on the internet for calculating lcm. My program is to calculate the lcm that is also divisible by the numbers between the smallest and largest.

Comment: Then you can't call it LCM . There can be only one LCM for two given numbers. Anything requires a third condition is not called LCM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for lcm, or least common multiple. It so happens that `lcm(a, b) = a * b / gcd(a, b)` where gcd is greatest common divisor, the largest number that both numbers are a multiple of. There is an algorithm called the Euclidean Algorithm for quickly calculating gcd: `gcd(a, b) = gcd(b, a % b)` where `a%b` is `a modulo b`. In javascript, it is this.

```
function gcd(a, b) {
    if (b === 0) {
        return a; // so that the recursion does not go on forever
    } else {
        return gcd(b, a % b);
    }
}
```

Then, you can define lcm like this.

```
function lcm(a, b) {
    return a * b / gcd(a, b);
}
```

EDIT: In order to calculate the lcm of a list of numbers, just reduce with the lcm function. So in order to calculate the lcm of all numbers in a range, this code will work. (assuming the range is inclusive for the 2 arguments)

```
function lcmOfRange(a, b) {
    let range = [];
    for (let i = a; i <= b; i++) {
        range.push(i);
    }
    return lcmOfList(range);
}

function lcmOfList(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(lcm);
}
```

This is equivalent to

```
function lcmOfRange(a, b) {
    let result = a;
    for (let i = a + 1; i <= b; i++) {
        result = lcm(result, i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I found the previous question for calculating lcm.There is also lots of code on the internet for calculating lcm. My program is to calculate the lcm that is also divisible by the numbers between the smallest and largest.

Comment: @DanielSemel I have edited my answer to show how to get the lcm of a list.